# How does one demonstrate that philosophy isn’t a time sink?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Why should anyone else’s thoughts on any philosophical subject bear any more importance than mine? You will read this and presume arrogance but this isn’t about me.

The question is more general. Before reading others’ philosophies, why should one assume that your thoughts about the matter on a particular subject are less important than others? It’s not as if this is a science class where we can verifiably show that one person knows about reality more than another such as in the case of physics, math, or whatever else.

It is about how one can justify **why** one needs to read other philosophers on subjects such as whether the external world is real. Perhaps they may have insights on something that you haven’t thought of so I can see the use there. But one thing is for sure: they do not have any more **knowledge** than me, or you. All one can say is that one person has read more philosophy than another, **not** that he knows more, and the justification of the need to do this instead of spending time elsewhere is the very thing in question.

Why then should one bother reading other philosophers’ opinions on things and potentially waste their time and life on unknowable matters instead of just going with whatever their gut, instinct, or thoughts tell them? If this can’t be justified, then it seems that the project of treating philosophy as a matter that helps you learn more about the world (instead of people’s **opinions** about the world) is in ruin.

Comment: Studying philosophy helped me understand set theory better, studying set theory has led to me understanding mathematics more, which has helped me grasp physics better, too. The payoff is perhaps contingent but it's still there.

Comment: So it helped you learn more about the world only through a theory that is based on mathematics as an unintended consequence.

Comment: Why are you asking us?

Comment: @Baby_philosopher *was* it an unintended consequence, or did studying theories of properties, types, intensions, quantification, logic, etc. help me understand the foundations of mathematics better for the sake of this very understanding, which meant understanding mathematics better, etc.?

Comment: I'm disappointed. I wonder if my previous comment was taken to be just a joke. The OP could give us some serious insight on this question by explaining why they posted this question.

Comment: Because knowing what is and what isn’t a waste of time is important

Comment: Y'know, I was just thinking about that too. I will ponder the synchronicity.

Comment: Because it is the only option. Otherwise, you wouldn't ask.

Comment: looks like you're confusing philosophy and metaphysics, which is only a part of it.

Answer (score 3):

> Why then should one bother reading other philosophers’ opinions on things and potentially waste their time and life on unknowable matters instead of just going with whatever their gut, instinct, or thoughts tell them?

**To pursue philosophy is to be animated by the belief that language and reason are beneficial in life, and reading the language and reason of others provides us a model for our own language and reason.** If I have an interest in mathematics, and want to prove [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), perhaps I believe that I can do it entirely with my high school education, but by reading about the efforts of others, I can learn, and that learning may assist me in actually devising a proof.

**Philosophy can seem to be about unimportant or trivial matters, but philosophy is a topic that also encompasses very pragmatic issues like life, death, and law.** [Marcus Aurelius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Aurelius) writes about how to deal with problems in life, and how to react to one's life and death. Positive psychologists are greatly interested in how wisdom leads to more happiness and better satisfaction in life. Being able to reason to a likely outcome with an awareness of science and probability means that choices more in line with one's goals can be decided.

**Instincts, first impressions, and gut reactions are often wrong.** One very important philosophical idea is the notion of [fallibilism (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/fallibil/). Just because we believe we are right doesn't mean we are right. Philosophy helps find places where our [cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias) and fallacies are lurking.

Ultimately, history shows that calm, rational thinking tends to prevail over emotional, biased thinking. It is the slow and steady accumulation that has helped shaped the evolution of human culture from small, predatory hunter bands into contemporary, technical society. **Whether one can chooses to maximize those advantages conferred by the society and the Enlightenment is a choice everyone must make for themselves.**

Comment: Everyone has an opinions, but some opinions evince expertise.

Comment: Another way to look at it: A smart person learns from their own successes and failures. A wise person learns from the successes and failures of others.

Answer (score 0):

Most issues are not "one-dimensional". Even if you think you have understood something already, other people have different perspectives from where they analyze a problem that you might have completely missed. They might bring in completely new framework of thinking that might be a good tool to use.

This is true for every day problems. But philosophy deals with the basic questions and tries to find the "roots" of the ideas. Or even creates these "roots".

Even if you think some philosophy is completely bonkers: It might still be worth reading as at lets you help understand others who follow those philosophies. It helps you understand how other people "tick".

So you will be able to get a mental grid that you can use to quickly reason about new problems.

Last but not least it helps you communicate: By knowing this mental grid and being able to reference to it you can communicate with others who also have read the same philosophy. Instead of spending hours explaining something you can refer to common thoughts.

So certainly philosophy is far from being "a waste of time".

Answer (score 0):

Whether an activity is useful or a time-sink depends on your circumstances and objectives.

If you are a professional philosopher, philosophy is a means of earning money, so in that respect it is no more of a time-sink than any other job.

If you are a dabbler, you might find philosophy to be an interesting intellectual puzzle- akin to doing the crossword- or simply an entertainment- akin to reading novels. If you consider the crossword and novels to be time-sinks, then philosophy probably is too.

A lot of philosophy- like a lot of literary criticism- is ultimately a matter of opinion, and you are as entitled to your opinion as the next person.

One reason to read the words of some philosophers is that they might have thought about certain things more than you have, and they might have arrived at a clarity of understanding that contrasts with your own muddled thinking on a topic. You don't have to read many questions on this site to realise that some people struggle to think clearly- and perhaps for people in that position, reading the views of other people who have clearer insights might be a help. Of course, that means you have to be selective in your reading- there are some philosophers who will be no help at all to the reader seeking clarity, owing to their remarkable inability or unwillingness to express themselves clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should anyone else’s thoughts on any philosophical subject bear any more importance than mine?

It is not either or. We are not supposed to choose between different perspectives and opinions. What we should be doing, instead, is to treat all this information, as well as our own insights, as pieces of the puzzle. This puzzle, should one succeed as completing it, will become their own understanding of the Reality.